# Mr. Jones and the logical conundrum

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

After successfully finding the treasure in
[The treasure hunt of Mr. Jones](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48356/the-treasure-hunt-of-mr-jones), it turned out that the treasure was not so magnificent after all and barely covered the cost of the guides.

Mr. Jones had no choice but to go on his next treasure hunt.

Here we are now in front of a new maze of rooms hiding a new treasure to be found!

According to some information collected beforehand, it would seems that the rooms are connected as such :

> 1 -> 2,4
>   2 -> 1,3,5
>   3 -> 2,6
>   4 -> 1,5,7
>   5 -> 2,4,6,8
>   6 -> 3,5,9
>   7 -> 4,8
>   8 -> 5,7,9,10
>   9 -> 6,8
>   10 -> 8

And the treasure should be in room number 10.

In the entrance, in front of the maze, a big stone table with a red button in the middle can be seen. After further investigation, the following scribbles from previous treasure hunters were found carved on the table :

> X
>     E  F
>   B  C  D
>     9  A
>   6  7  8
>     4  5
>   1  2  3
>
> 1 = 2!&3
>   2 = 1|3
>   3 = 1!&2
>   4 = 1
>   5 = 3
>   6 = 1X!|3
>   7 = 2&9&A
>   8 = 6X|B
>   9 = BX|D
>   A = 9X|B
>   B = !D
>   C = B&D
>   D = 4!|5
>   E = 3X!|B
>   F = 6X!|8
>   X = E!|F

Behind the table, the doors leading to room 1,2 and 3 could be accessed.
Mr. Jones then proceeded to open the door to the room 2, but it was locked.
Perplexed, he then tried to open the door to the room 3 and it was unlocked!
He then entered the room number 3 and proceeded to open the door in front of him, but it was locked.
Frustrated, Mr Jones went back outside and tried to open the door to room 2 again. "HaHa!" he exclaimed as the door opened.  After entering room 2, he tried to open the door in front of him but it was locked.
The now fulminating Mr Jones went back outside and smashed the red button on the table. To his surprise, all the doors were automatically closed.

Can you help Mr. Jones find the treasure?

HINT

> After regaining his calm, Mr. Jones decided to try one more time. He went into the room 1 without problem, but the door in front of him was locked, he went back out and into the room 2 again without problem. He went back out and tried to go into room 3 but the door would not open. Back into room 2, he was able to open the doors to his left but then could not progress any further. Back to the reset button!

Comment: I didn't even try to solve it yet, but I can make sense of most of it. There are only a couple things bothering me that require some clarifications in my opinion : A door has three states : locked (closed), unlocked (closed) and opened, right? The "mechanisms" on each door are active as long as the door is open, correct? And then come problems of comprehension of the tablet : for example, is "3X!|B" the same as "3 & X! | B" or does it mean "3! & X! | B"?

Comment: @DorianFusco Once a door is opened, it stays open as long as you don't hit the reset button. As for the scribbles, it is part of the mystery that must be solved. I am sorry but that is all I am willing to say for now.

Comment: I'm really not sure we have enough informations to break the "Treasure Hunter code". The problem being that, assuming "|" means "OR", "&" means "AND" and "!" means "NOT" (although it should be placed before a statement, not after one, or, as I suspect, before an operator), no door could be unlocked at the beginning, so the only conclusion I can have is that I'm misinterpreting (some of) the operators, but I can't guess their meaning with that few information, I'd need Mr Jones to try more doors to figure it out. As of now, I can only make sense out of "a = b|c" thanks to the 2nd door he opened

Comment: Unless "a = b !& c" actually means "a = !b | !c" and "a = b !| c" means "a = !b & !c", but, again, I can't make sure of that because of the lack of information...

Comment: @DorianFusco: I think it might be more than just boolean operators, since the door to room 5 (the door he tried inside room 2) should have been unlocked if that's the case (since I assume 5=3 means if 3 is unlocked 5 is unlocked as well).

Comment: @DorianFusco A hint to reward your hard work! Your interpretation of the scribbles is not totally wrong, but not totally right either. Maybe try to think slightly less like a programmer and more like a ....

Comment: @justhalf ; The door he tried inside room 2 wasn't door 5 though. But in the new hint, he did open door 4 and 5, although according to my logic so far, one of these should have remained shut. Stack Reader ; Like a treasure hunter? I'm trying, but being a programmer doesn't help ! I'll try to figure something with the new hint :)

Comment: @DorianFusco: Ahh, I was thinking the numbers as the room numbers, not door numbers. Already thought about xnor and nand, but since my assumption was wrong, I couldn't continue. I was thinking how can one represents the door between two rooms, but it didn't occur to me that the numbers in the scribbling *are* indeed the door numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rooms look like (10 is 0):

> `|123|`
> `|456|`
> `|789|`
> `| 0 |`

The doors look like this (T is treasure, R for room):

> `|1   2   3|`
> `|-   -   -|`
> `|R|4|R|5|R|`
> `|-   -   -|`
> `|6   7   8|`
> `|-   -   -|`
> `|R|9|R|A|R|`
> `|-   -   -|`
> `|B   C   D|`
> `|-   -   -|`
> `|R|E|R|F|R|`
> `|    -    |`
> `|    X    |`
> `|    -    |`
> `|    T    |`

Here is my interpretation of the symbols:

> `!` is `n`
>  `X` is `x` except for the last clue

So:

> `1 = 2 nand 3`
> `2 = 1 or   3`
> `3 = 1 nand 2`
> `4 = 1`
> `5 = 3`
> `6 = 1 xnor 3`
> `7 = 2 and  9 and  A`
> `8 = 6 xor  B`
> `9 = B xor  D`
> `A = 9 xor  B`
> `B =   not  D`
> `C = B and  D`
> `D = 4 nor  5`
> `E = 3 xnor B`
> `F = 6 xnor 8`
> `X = E nor  F`

Then:

> A door is represented as high if and only if the door is open (and unlocked). Furthermore, if the right-hand-side of the 'equation' is high, the door on the left is unlocked, otherwise it is either already open or locked.

A way to get to the treasure and to open every door:

> `1, 3, 2, 6, 8, B, A, 9, D, 4, 5, 7, C, X, E, F`

Comment: Mr. Jones is very grateful for your help!

Comment: @stackreader Was it necessary to open all the doors or were E and F just in there as a distraction?

Comment: If they were opened at any point before the treasure room, the door would be forever locked. There was no need to open them. But there was a need to not open them.

Comment: @stackreader , in your hint, how could Mr Jones open door 4 and 5? Room 3 was locked

Comment: @DorianFusco Seems like I made a slight mistake about door 5. Must have written the hint too quickly. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: I did more than noticing, it bugged me a lot, I thought I still hadn't understood the Treasure Hunter code, but I actually did (except the XOR, XNOR, XAND and XNAND, I never new these operators even existed so I would have still been unable to fully solve it) ! Anyway, since the other treasure hunters had information on how door X would open, I can only hope they already got to the treasure roomn abd Mr Jones will have no choice but to go onto his next journey !

Comment: By the way, @stackreader , you could have been an evil riddler and swap the doors along the axe of symmetry of the maze, door 1 would lead to room 3 and door 3 would lead to room 1, confusing everyone from the get go :p

Comment: @DorianFuscom XAND and XNAND don't exist (though NAND does).